# How do you pass a (Claims) security Token to a WIF enabled WCF service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, wif, adfs

my escope :

How do you pass a (Claims) security Token to a WIF enabled WCF service?

Implement security asp mvc (ok)

Implement security in wcf (not ok)

Pass the token from client to wcf.(not ok)

My code client

```
    using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.ServiceModel.Security;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust;
    using Nobre.Core.Helpers;
    using Wcf;


    namespace Mvc.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            [Authorize]
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                var securityToken = WcfHelper.GetActAsToken(identity.BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext);
                var serviceAddress = "https://estnbr363.nobre.local/Service1.svc";
                var binding = new WSFederationHttpBinding();

                binding.Security.Mode = WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
                binding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Rsa15;
                binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = true;
                binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.SymmetricKey;
                binding.Security.Message.IssuedTokenType ="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#samlv1.1";

                var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, serviceAddress);
                factory.ConfigureChannelFactory();
                factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
                var channel = factory.CreateChannelActingAs(securityToken);  

                return View( channel.GetData(1));

            }
        }
    }


    web config service         
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="https://nobre-security.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
    <add key="ida:Issuer" value="https://nobre-security.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" />
    <add key="ida:ProviderSelection" value="ACS" />
  </appSettings>
  <location path="FederationMetadata">
    <system.web>
      <!--<authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>-->
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <!--<authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>-->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging maxMessagesToLog="25000" logEntireMessage="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"  logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true">
        <filters>
          <clear/>
        </filters>
      </messageLogging>
    </diagnostics>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <ws2007FederationHttpBinding >
        <binding >
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message  issuedKeyType="BearerKey" negotiateServiceCredential="true">
              <issuerMetadata address="https://federation.nobre.net.br/adfs/services/trust/mex" />
            </message>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Wcf.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="">
        <endpoint name="ws2007FederationHttpBinding.Service1" address="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" contract="Wcf.IService1" />
      </service>    
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://estnbr363.nobre.local/Service1.svc" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry">
        <authority name="https://nobre-security.accesscontrol.windows.net/">
          <keys>
            <add thumbprint="213D414F8E89D865FD10A49C8C8F838A9460EBEE" />
          </keys>
          <validIssuers>
            <add name="https://nobre-security.accesscontrol.windows.net/" />
          </validIssuers>
        </authority>
      </issuerNameRegistry>      
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>  
</configuration>
```

line error

```
channel.GetData(1);
```

The address of the issuer of the security token was not specified. An explicit issuer address must be specified on the link to 'https://estnbr363.nobre.local/Service1.svc' destination or sender's address location must be configured in the credentials.

```
the problem are these lines below! how to implement ?

  // Extract the STS certificate from the certificate store. ?????????
      X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
      X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(
          X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", false);
      store.Close();

      // Create an EndpointIdentity from the STS certificate. ???????????
      EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.CreateX509CertificateIdentity ( certs[0] );

      // Set the IssuerAddress using the address of the STS and the previously created ???????

      // EndpointIdentity.
      b.Security.Message.IssuerAddress = 
          new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:8000/sts/x509"), identity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this

```
factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
```

turned off CardSpace for me. Just place it after the `ConfigureChannelFactory()` in the client code.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index(){
    var identity = HttpContext.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var securityToken = WcfHelper.GetActAsToken(identity.BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext);   
    string serviceAddress = "svc";
    var binding = new     WS2007FederationHttpBinding(WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
    var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding,new EndpointAddress(serviceAddress));
    factory.ConfigureChannelFactory();
    factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
    var channel = factory.CreateChannelActingAs(securityToken);
    channel.DoWork();
}
```

**SupportInterative:**

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the system is allowed to
>   interactively prompt the user for credentials when necessary. For
>   example, setting it to false might be desired in middle-tier
>   scenarios.

Comment: channel.DoWork(); error The address of the issuer of the security token was not specified. An explicit issuer address must be specified on the link to 'https://estnbr363.nobre.local/Service1.svc' destination or sender's address location must be configured in the credentials.

Comment: That is a completely different problem. See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716218/wcf-client-error-the-address-of-the-security-token-issuer-is-not-specified

Comment: You should consider configuring a mex endpoint and the let Visual Studio generate the service reference for you. If you want to create the endpoint in code you have to look very closely at the bindings. You are missing all the stuff about the security configuration. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.servicemodel.federatedmessagesecurityoverhttp.issueraddress.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help but the error remains the same.

I posted the code in top, can you help me?